# Scala type mismatch after adding if/else if condition

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Sorry for the dumb question. I am new to Scala and not sure how Scala works.
The code works good without if /else if condition. But when I add the if /else if condition, it complains:

```
ScoreTable.scala:172:10: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: String
[error]     else if ("test2".equalsIgnoreCase(adTypeInput)) {
[error]          ^
```

How should I fix it? Adjust private def method(): String to private def method(): Any?

```
private def method(): String = {
    val spark2 = spark
    import spark2.implicits._
    if ("test1".equalsIgnoreCase(adTypeInput)) {
    var table = (
        spark.read.parquet("path")
          ...
          ...
          .distinct()
      )
    table.select("propensity").summary().show(truncate = false)
    IOUtil.output(f"generate raw table with size: ${table.count()}")
    writeLocalTable(table)
   } else if("test2".equalsIgnoreCase(adTypeInput)) {
      spark.read.parquet("path")
      ...
      ...
    table.select("propensity").summary().show(truncate = false)
    IOUtil.output(f"generate raw table with size: ${table.count()}")
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Scala is expression-oriented.

Scala `if(...) ... else ...` is not like Java `if(...) {...} else {...}`, it's more like Java ternary operator `... ? ... : ...`. You can assign its value to some variable:

```
val x = if (...) ... else ...
```

In Scala every block returns the last expression.

So in

```scala
if ("test1".equalsIgnoreCase(adTypeInput)) {
   ...
} else if("test2".equalsIgnoreCase(adTypeInput)) {
   ...
}
```

the 1st block

```scala
var table = (
  spark.read.parquet("path")
    ...
    ...
  .distinct()
)
table.select("propensity").summary().show(truncate = false)
IOUtil.output(f"generate raw table with size: ${table.count()}")
writeLocalTable(table)
```

returns the value of `writeLocalTable(table)`. I suspect it's `Unit`?

The 2nd block

```scala
spark.read.parquet("path")
  ...
  ...
table.select("propensity").summary().show(truncate = false)
IOUtil.output(f"generate raw table with size: ${table.count()}")
```

returns the value of `IOUtil.output(...)`. I suspect it's `Unit` too?

All branches of `if-else` must return values of the same type `A`, then the whole `if-else` expression returns a value of type `A`.

So now it's `Unit`. But in `def method(): String = ...` you promised that the method returns `String`. This is a type mismatch i.e. a compile error: `found: Unit, required: String`.

Either change the signature of the method: `def method(): Unit = ...` (but it's possible that you'll also have to change places where `method` is called i.e. where `String` is still expected) or return a `String` from every branch as promised in the signature

```scala
if ("test1".equalsIgnoreCase(adTypeInput)) {
  ...
  writeLocalTable(table)
  "what string?"
} else if ("test2".equalsIgnoreCase(adTypeInput)) {
  ...
  IOUtil.output(...)
  "what string here?"
}
```

or let `if-else` return `Unit` but return `String` from the method

```scala
private def method(): String = {
  ...
  if ("test1".equalsIgnoreCase(adTypeInput)) {
    ...
  } else if ("test2".equalsIgnoreCase(adTypeInput)) {
    ...
  } else {
    // what if adTypeInput is neither "test1" nor "test2"? 
  }

  "what string to return?"
}
```

You should look what `String` was returned before your change with `if-else`.